# whole number solution using permutation and combination

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am trying to solve [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/UJ/) question. What I have understood is that we can solve the problem using the following method.Suppose we have to divide $x$ CD's among $4$ nephews answer will be simply Number of whole number solution of  $a+b+c+d = x$ which is ${x+3 \choose 3}$. (According to me this should be solution)

But on internet it is given answer is $4^x$. This solution also seems correct to me (sorry I am bad at math). Can someone explain the difference between two methods and when to use which method?

Comment: Each CD has a unique title (they are distinguishable) so it matters which nephew gets which CD, and not just how many CDs each nephew gets. Each CD can be given to one of the four nephews, so the number of outcomes is $4 \cdot 4 \cdots 4 = 4^x$.

Comment: aaah, I get it thanx :)

Comment: Please make problems self-contained so the answers will still make sense if the link goes stale.